# Difference between the following in css display?

Tags: css

I was asked a question, whats the difference between the following and I did not really know the answer. So here it goes, what is the difference between,

```
display:inline-block 
display:inline
display:block
```

thanks for your answers...

Comment: w3schools has the answer: [CSS display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: -1 because you obviously haven't bothered looking it up.  You could find the answer many many many times over on google.

Comment: NO, block and inline-block seem to exhibit the same behaviour. I have actually used them interchangeably. Also I believe SO is trying to build its own db of questions. I did check here and did not find an answer to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main one you are struggling with is inline-block from your comment under your question.

inline-block is a way to get block elements to appear inline, so instead of floating a load of divs left, you could use inline-block on them, preserving their behaviour as divs but making them inline elements instead.

For example lets say you have

```
​<div style="display:block" >Test</div>
<div style="display:block" >Home</div>​
```

This will render as

> Test
>
> Home

Where as

```
​<div style="display:inline-block" >Test</div>
<div style="display:inline-block" >Home</div>​
```

will display as

> TestHome

In addition, inline elements can't have width/height attributes. Block elements can. `inline-block` makes a block element look like an inline element but you can still apply styles that only block elements can have. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QJpX8/1).

Comment: This is the same as when I use inline on them instead of inline block

Comment: yes but using inline on them now makes it an inline element, this no longer acts as a block element, whereas inline-block makes it act like a block but appear inline.

Comment: So, a block element has spaces on the top and the bottom, unlike the inline element. http://jsfiddle.net/QJpX8/

Comment: Is there some property of the block element that I am missing which inline block brings in?

Comment: block elements are not inline elements, thereofre to make block elements appear inline but remain as block elements you have to use inline-block.  I suggest you read up on the differences between inline and block.  Block elements by default take up the entire width with a new line before and after, inline elements are, well, inline.

Comment: @Shouvik, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/QJpX8/1/ Inline elements can't have width/height attributes. Block elements can. `inline-block` makes a block element look like an inline element but you can still apply styles that only block elements can have.

Comment: @sachleen: that I can see and makes a lot of sense, please post as answer and I will select it...

Comment: @Shouvik Jon's answer is pretty good. I've just added mine on to his.

Comment: accepted :). Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @sachleen thanks, I didn't mention specifically what block can do over inline just because this is something which can be looked up very easily.  Never the less, its still a good addition to the asnwer so I will add your comment into my answer.

Comment: lol I see you edited it too haha :)